# Multiple Try/Except for Validate Config-File

Tags: python, validation, config

Thats my first question on Stackoverflow and im a totally Python beginner.

I want to write, to get firm with python, a small Backup-Programm, the main part is done, but now i want to make it a bit "portable" and use a Config file, which i want to Validate.

My class "getBackupOptions" should be give Back a validate dict which should be enriched with "GlobalOptions" and "BackupOption" so that i finally get an fully "BackupOption" dict when i call "getBackupOptions.BackupOptions".

My Question now is, (in this Example is it easy, because its only the Function which check if the Path should be Recursive searched or not) how to simplify my Code?
For each (possible) Error i must write a new "TryExcept" Block - Can i Simplify it?

Maybe is there another way to Validate Config Files/Arrays?

```
class getBackupOptions:
    def __init__(self,BackupOption,GlobalOptions):
        self.BackupOption = BackupOption
        self.GlobalOptions = GlobalOptions

        self.getRecusive()


def getRecusive(self):
    try:
        if self.BackupOption['recursive'] != None:
            pass
    else:
            raise KeyError
    except KeyError:
        try:
            if self.GlobalOptions['recursive'] != None:
                self.BackupOption['recursive'] = self.GlobalOptions['recursive']
            else:
                raise KeyError
        except KeyError:
            print('Recusive in: ' + str(self.BackupOption) + ' and Global is not set!')
            exit()
```

Actually i only catch an KeyError, but what if the the Key is there but there is something else than "True" or "False"?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
class getBackupOptions:
    def __init__(self,BackupOption,GlobalOptions):
        self.BackupOption = BackupOption
        self.GlobalOptions = GlobalOptions

        self.getRecusive()

    def getRecusive(self):
        if self.BackupOption.get('recursive') == 'True' and self.GlobalOptions.get('recursive') == 'True':
            self.BackupOption['recursive'] = self.GlobalOptions['recursive']
        else:
            print('Recusive in: ' + str(self.BackupOption) + ' and Global is not set!')
            exit()
```

- Here `get` method is used, therefore `KeyError` will not be faced.
- If any text other than `True` comes in the field it will be considered as `False`.